# What function can be used to create an image from a matrix of colors?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to replicate the annotation image seen below, by creating a matrix of colors based on annotations I have created:

```
ann1 <- c("blue", "red", "green", "red")
ann2 <- c("black", "gray", "yellow", "white")
ann3 <- c("orange", "blue", "pink", "green")
object <- cbind(ann1, ann2, ann3)
```

Which function can I use? (you don't need you to do the work!)

[image: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v489/n7417/images/nature11404-f1.2.jpg]

Finished product for future reference:

```
ann1 <- c("blue", "blue", "red", "red")
ann2 <- c("black", "gray", "black", "black")
ann3 <- c("red", "red", "red", "green")
object <- cbind(ann1, ann2, ann3)
colnames(object) <- c("group1", "group2", "group3")
image(matrix(1:length(object), nrow(object), ncol(object)), col=object, yaxt='n', xaxt='n', yaxs="i")
par(las=1)
increment <- seq(0,1, by=(1/(ncol(object)-1)))
increment <- increment[1:ncol(object)]
axis(side=2, at=increment, labels=colnames(object))
```

[image]

Comment: You can look into the "image" function, which can be used to make colored grids

Answer (score 2):

One way to get you started...

```
ann1 <- c("blue", "red", "green", "red")
ann2 <- c("black", "gray", "yellow", "white")
ann3 <- c("orange", "blue", "pink", "green")
object <- cbind(ann1, ann2, ann3)

image(t(matrix(1:12, 4, 3)), col=object)
```

[image]

Comment: @user1854603 Good deal. Thanks for posting what you ended up using.